# `xdg-open` does not open files in the preferred applicaton

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, mime-type, xdg-open

`xdg-open` does not work as expected. It opens most my files in browser, directories in my code editor(VS code) and plain text files using `less`. It also throws this error message,

```
$ xdg-open $HOME
xdg-mime: mimetype argument missing
Try 'xdg-mime --help' for more information.
```

then it opens the folder in my code editor. Whereas,

```
$ xdg-mime query default inode/directory
org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
```

the default file manager application is `Nautilus`. How do I fix this?

Comment: What does running the command `exo-preferred-applications` show for your default File Manager?

Comment: exo-utils isn't installed, should I install it?

Comment: Yes, install the `exo-utils`.  It can be quite helpful.

Comment: It shows "No preferred application" for file manager

Comment: That's why it is not working.   Select Nautilus in the drop down and that should fix it.

Comment: Didn't work, still opens code editor :(

Comment: What does the Exec= line in `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop` show?

Comment: It shows "nautilus --new-window". BTW this problem is not specific to my file manager. Like images are opened in browser instead of image viewer. I guess it somethings the problem with xdg-open

Comment: Try rebooting now that you selected Nautilus as the default.  I don't know what else to tell you as mine works fine.  And your settings are now set like mine.  The only other thing I can think of is if you're using Wayland instead of an X desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer suggests that Gnome uses `gvfs-open` in the background.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144048/421466

`gvfs-open` has been deprecated and the new command is `gio open`.

```
$ gio open
libffi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Running `gio open` threw this error. This error was due to python looking for libffi6.so file which wasn't present in my environment. I am using miniconda and there are other people as well who are facing this issue. Most of the answers suggests to create a symlink for `libffi6.so` or reinstall python,

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9957

https://stackoverflow.com/q/61875869/11701676

But simply installing libffi, using conda fixed the issue.

`conda install libffi`

Answer (score 0):

the `xdg-mime` is unable to determine the appropriate application to use to open the file. This can cause `xdg-open` to open files in the wrong application.

1. Check the default applications: Run the command `xdg-mime query default <mimetype>` to check the default application associated with the specific mimetype. For example, `xdg-mime query default inode/directory` will show the default file manager application.
2. Set the default application: If the default application is not set or incorrect, you can set it using the command `xdg-mime default <application.desktop> <mimetype>`. For example, to set Nautilus as the default file manager, run `xdg-mime default org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop inode/directory`.

After following these steps, `xdg-open` should be able to open files in the preferred application.