# All files open in browser

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, launcher, mime-type, xdg-open

**Description**

All files, no matter their type, and no matter what application I associate with the type, open with my default browser (Firefox), which then asks me to choose an application. This is very annoying.

It doesn't matter if I double-click, right-click and explicitly choose with which application to open the file, or even `xdg-open file.name`, the file always opens with Firefox.

**Context**

I believe it happened after I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 a few weeks ago. I have now upgraded to 20.04 for this reason, but it did not help.

**More information**

Consider CSV files for instance... I have this association visible via `xdg-mime`:

```
$ xdg-mime query default text/csv
libreoffice-calc.desktop
```

I have this association visible in "Files":

[image]

I also have this (just in case):

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache | grep csv
application/csv=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
text/csv=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
text/x-csv=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
```

Finally, I searched for all `mimeapps.list` and `defaults.list` files on my computer, and either they specify nothing, or point to `libreoffice-calc.desktop`.

**Similar questions**

I have seen people report similar problems, but nothing discussed there has helped:

- [How to properly and easy configure `xdg-open` without any environment?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36380/how-to-properly-and-easy-configure-xdg-open-without-any-environment)
- [`xdg-open` does not open files in the preferred applicaton](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1292612/xdg-open-does-not-open-files-in-the-preferred-applicaton)

Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: Does it happen if you create/use a new user?

Comment: Interestingly, no. My two new users (one admin and one standard) are free from this problem. Hm...

Comment: I haven't checked into any of this, sorry... but you seem to know the places to check. you can compare all the related files/configs between the two accounts (if you havent done so already)

Comment: It worked. Thanks to you I was able to locate and solve the problem (if not able to understand the exact cause).

Comment: Where was the problem?  It can be usefull for others to know.

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen As I wrote in my answer, on visual inspection the `mimeapps.list` file seemed fine. However, deleting it and restarting the computer fixed the problem. So I know where the problem was, but not what it was...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @WU-TANG, I was able to determine the file that was causing the problem, namely `~/.config/mimeapps.list`. Simply deleting it and restarting fixed the problem.

However, I still don't understand *why* this was happening. There was nothing obviously wrong with the file's contents, and `xdg-mime query default` was showing the correct association.

Comment: Obviously back up the file before deleting it.